# Two pages both showing as "First Page" making headers a pain

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

I'm not sure how I did this to my Word document, but there's two pages that are labeled with "First Page Header".  Of course, with things fouled up like this, I can't make the first page have a different header because it causes page two to have the same header.

(I actually want the first page to have no header, and the headers to start on page 2)

How can I get the second page to know it's the second page?  The header on the THIRD page of the document identifies itself as simply "Header Section 9".

MS Word 2007

Top and bottom of the first two pages:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The headers/footers are per section. So you can have a first page header (and a "regular" header) in Section 1, but not in section 2.

When the insertion point is in the header area of the section you want to change, with the ribbon showing "Design" and "Header and footer tools" you should be able to uncheck the "Different First Page box.

If the header on the third page shows "Section 9", it sounds as if you either have a lot of continuous page section breaks, or hidden text. You should be able to display most of these things using the show/hide button (Home tab, Paragraph group).

It's also possible, though rather less likely, that some of your document's content is being inserted by field codes in which case you need to use Alt-F9 to toggle between "field code" view and "field results" view" to see what is going on.

It's also possible that your document is corrupt.

Answer (score 0):

On Word in a Mac, you need to uncheck "link to previous" in the `Header and Footer` menu

[image]